# Variable definition in C

Tags: c, variables, declaration

What does following declaration mean in C?

```
char a = (10,23,21);
```

While printing the value of "a" with "%u" the output is 21.
`gcc` is not giving any error.
What's this kinda declaration and what's the use of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a use of the scalar comma operator. The comma operator evaluates each expression on the left side and throws away the return value, finally returning the rightmost value.

In this case, it's useless; however, if you use it with expressions with side-effects, then it has a real effect.

Example of a semi-"useful" expression (with side-effects):

```
int a = 10;
int is_a_odd_after_increment = ++a, a % 2;
```

The first expression (`++a`) has a clear side-effect, and it is evaluated first (before the `a % 2`). The second expression is the expression that is yielded into the assignment.

Comment: @Prathamesh Ease up on the quotation marks. You sound twelve.  The side-effect of ++a is that a is incremented.  Even though the results of the operation are thrown out, the operation still happens. ++a returns a and increments a.

Comment: so can there be an expression like if(condition) at the place of a?

Comment: @Prathamesh Yes, but you should never ever do that. Raptors will come out and eat you.

Comment: @Platinum Azure DERP! please disregard, as I am a twelve year old.

Comment: @Prathamesh: You can't use `if (condition)` in the middle of an expression, because `if (condition) { statements }` is considered a statement. An expression can be a statement (e.g., `++a;`), but you can't put a statement in the middle of an expression. You CAN put a comma operator expression as part of an if condition, because `if` takes an expression as its condition.

Answer (score 7):

You are seeing the comma operator at work. The comma operator `a,b` evaluates `a`, throws away the result, then returns `b`.

Since `10` and `23` have no side effects, this is equivalent to `char a = 21;`

Comment: Yes. `10` and `23` are discarded. The comma operator is only really useful when the left side has side-effects, eg `(x++,42)`.

Comment: so can there be an expression like if(condition) at the place of a?

Comment: `if` is a statement, not an expression, and so cannot be used in a comma operator expression. You can, however, use the `?:` ternary operator